# Cannot cast object '[Ljava.lang.Object;@589d360c' with class '[Ljava.lang.Object;' Exception in grails

Tags: grails

I am getting cast exception in grails application when i try to execute query which has multiple tables 
**UserLogin userList= UserLogin.find("from UserLogin as ul, UserDetails as ud where ul.id=ud.id")**

**UserLogin.groovy**

```
class UserLogin {

    String id
    String userName
    String pwd
    static constraints = {

    }

    static mapping = {
        table '[UserLogin]'
        version false
         id column : 'Id', generator: "assigned"
        userName column: 'UserName'
        pwd column:'Password'
    }
}
```

**UserDetails.groovy**

```
class UserDetails {

    int id
    String name
    String age

    static mapping={
        table '[UserDetails]'
        version false
         id column : 'Id', generator: "assigned"
        name column:'Name'
        age column:'Age'
    }
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Full stack trace**

> URI:/LearnGrails/userLogin/show/2Class:org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastExceptionMessage:Cannot
>   cast object '[Ljava.lang.Object;@589d360c' with class
>   '[Ljava.lang.Object;' to class 'learngrails.UserLogin' due to:
>   groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching
>   constructor for: learngrails.UserLogin(learngrails.UserLogin,
>   learngrails.UserDetails)

**Environment - Grails 2.5.0 and Jdk1.7**

**I am getting this error when i use "find" and its working fine with "findAll"**. I am new to grails please help - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use find for your cross join. If you want to get single result use findAll with extra params:

```
def userList= UserLogin.findAll("from UserLogin as ul, UserDetails as ud where ul.id=ud.id", [max:1])
```